# Dynamic change of script source not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have two files. An HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
function update_layout()
{
    var new_source = document.createElement('script')
    new_source.src = 'script_code.js'
    new_source.type = 'text/javascript'
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(new_source)
}
function do_layout()
{
    alert(Lay_Table['nam'])
}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Update" onclick="update_layout();do_layout();"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

and an JavaScript file named "script_code.js":

```
Lay_Table = {}
Lay_Table['nam'] = 'US 104 Key'
```

When I click on the "Update" button I get an error instead of an alert containing the text "US 104 Key".

I have looked at very similar questions on Stack Overflow but cannot find out what is wrong. Have I made a mistake, or is this method no longer allowed due to security reasons? I am using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script takes a bit of time to get inserted into the document and run - it doesn't happen immediately, so the `Lay_Table` is not defined in time when `do_layout` runs. Consider adding a `load` listener to the inserted tag (and [avoid inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045), they have way too many problems to be worth using nowadays, such as a demented scope chain and quote escaping issues):

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', update_layout);
});
function update_layout()
{
    var new_source = document.createElement('script')
    new_source.src = 'script_code.js'
    new_source.addEventListener('load', do_layout);
    document.head.appendChild(new_source)
}
```

Comment: I need to run the `do_layout` function too. When I do I get the same error as before.

Comment: The `new_source.addEventListener('load', do_layout);` should run it only after the inserted script has loded.

Comment: Question: What do I do if I have more than one script that needs to load? Thanks.